# Postgres performs full table scan instead of applying other WHERE clause first

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PG query that is doing a full table scan when a (seemingly obvious) index should be used instead. It involves a `join` and `IN` as follows:

```
SELECT sequence.name
FROM sequence, annotation
WHERE sequence.id = annotation.sequence_id
AND lower(annotation.name) LIKE lower('my-query%')
AND sequence.folder_id IN (2504,  6039, 35);
```

`sequence.folder_id` is indexed:

```
# \d sequence_folder_id_idx
Index "public.sequence_folder_id_idx"
  Column   |  Type   | Definition
-----------+---------+------------
 folder_id | integer | folder_id
btree, for table "public.sequence"
```

And I'd expect it to first filter by `folder_id` and then filter by `annotation.name`. Instead, it does a full scan for `lower(annotation.name)`. Here's the query plan with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFER):

```
Hash Join  (cost=731.39..21141.97 rows=20 width=16) (actual time=526.315..526.315 rows=0 loops=1)
    Hash Cond: (annotation.sequence_id = sequence.id)
    Buffers: shared hit=695 read=8639
    ->  Seq Scan on annotation  (cost=0.00..20396.54 rows=3688 width=4) (actual time=526.314..526.314 rows=0 loops=1)
          Filter: (lower((name)::text) ~~ 'my-query%'::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 737503
          Buffers: shared hit=695 read=8639
    ->  Hash  (cost=724.65..724.65 rows=539 width=20) (never executed)
         ->  Index Scan using sequence_folder_id_idx on sequence  (cost=0.32..724.65 rows=539 width=20) (never executed)
               Index Cond: (folder_id = ANY ('{2504,6039,35}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 526.365 ms
```

As you can see, it scans through 737k rows to filter by `annotation.name` instead of first limiting by `folder_id`.

If I use `ANY( VALUES (2504) ...)` it works wonderfully:

```
SELECT sequence.name
FROM sequence, annotation
WHERE sequence.id = annotation.sequence_id
AND lower(annotation.name) LIKE lower('my-query%')
AND sequence.folder_id = ANY(VALUES (2504), (6039), (35));

Nested Loop  (cost=0.76..368.71 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=7.795..7.795 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1184
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.34..150.52 rows=103 width=20) (actual time=0.033..0.497 rows=292 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=96
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.05..0.08 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=3 loops=1)
              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=3 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using sequence_folder_id_idx on sequence  (cost=0.29..49.81 rows=34 width=24) (actual time=0.017..0.101 rows=97 loops=3)
              Index Cond: (folder_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
              Buffers: shared hit=96
  ->  Index Scan using annotation_sequence_id_idx on annotation  (cost=0.42..2.11 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=292)
        Index Cond: (sequence_id = sequence.id)
        Filter: (lower((name)::text) ~~ 'my-query%'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 12
        Buffers: shared hit=1088
Total runtime: 7.883 ms
```

Does anyone have a reasonable explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: Do a `vaccum analyze tbl_name` on both tables, first.

Comment: `vacuum analyze sequence; vacuum analyze annotation;` that is. BTW: `sequence` is a reserved word in postgresql, try to avoid it as an identifier.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried vacuum analyze, ran it on all the tables in the schema. Ran it again just in case, and no change. (BTW, probably obvious, but if I run the query with an invalid folder ID (e.g. change `12504` to `2504`) it switches to the index scan.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, 3688 is how many rows it think will pass the filter, not how many it think are in the table.

Comment: Are you really changing between 12504 and 2504, or is that a typo?

Comment: Oh god sorry, I sanitized the data a bit and went the wrong way. The real value is 2504, the 12504 is a typo.

Comment: It's actually the index on `annotation.sequence_id` which is being used differently in the second query (`sequence_folder_id_idx` is used in both). In order to do so, it is invoking a Nested Loop in place of a Hash Join, which would in many cases be a costlier strategy. I also note that in this particular example, no rows of `annotation` are actually being matched, leading to an explain output I'd not seen before: `(never executed)`.

Comment: Another thought: how selective is `annotation.sequence_id`? That is, how many rows generally exist with the same `sequence_id` value? Ditto `sequence.folder_id`? You may only have three integers to test against the first index, but if that means 100 rows from `sequence`, each with 100 rows in `annotation`, there are still 10000 rows to test the `like` clause against, at which point scanning down the whole table could genuinely be quicker.

Comment: Hm, so `annotation.sequence_id` can vary, there are a couple sequences with up to 10k, 23k annotations but it quickly drops to 1k. Similarly, the largest folder does have 5k sequences. So that's an interesting point, which is unfortunate because the common case is for it to match only a few hundred annotations and not 700k.

I think my solution is just going to be to create a varchar_pattern_ops index on annotation.name and be done with it.

Comment: I think that does make sense of the query planner's decision then: if testing the foreign key index first might (according to its statistics) require it to hold a list of several thousand row entries, then look them each up in the full table to test the text content, that's going to eat both RAM (for intermediate results) and disk I/O (jumping around finding the rows to test), whereas a table scan mostly takes CPU (and can even share buffers with other queries performing the same scan I believe).

Comment: Is it typical for your queries to return no rows? I bet the timing changes when an existing annotation name is selected. Also a question, how many annotation names you have?